# SQL, max(), group by

Tags: sql, group-by, max

My Question - 
On applying `group by`, I need to do `MAX` on some criteria of a column, but select that column (not the criteria I used to evaluate max). Help needed.

Ex,
Let's say I have a column called `RuleUID` which has values like `70_rule`, `110_rule`, `120_rule` etc. Now I want to do something like this.

```
select firstname, lastname, MAX( CAST(SUBSTRING(RuleUID,1,CHARINDEX('_',RuleUID)-1) AS INT) as **?????**
from employee
group by firstname, lastname
```

In the above snippet, I need to be able to choose RuleUid(in **?????**) which corresponded to that `MAX` criteria. How do I go about this.

Comment: You want to **???.RuleUID**?

Comment: What variety of SQL are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL ...)?

Comment: Yes I need RuleUID to be selected which corresponded to that MAX criteria, I am using sql server

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to select the firstname, lastname, whatever the max function returns **and the RuleUID**?

Comment: I need to select the first name, lastname, and rulUid which returns evaluates to that max condition.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to solve this. One is to compare the same substring of `RuleUID` with the `MAX` value:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, RuleUID
FROM employee
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(RuleUID,1,CHARINDEX('_',RuleUID)-1) AS INT) =
          (SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(RuleUID,1,CHARINDEX('_',RuleUID)-1) AS INT)) 
           FROM employee)
```

Another is to add the `_rule` part of the value back to the `MAX` value and compare that directly. This should be more efficient as you can use an index on `RuleUID`:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, RuleUID
FROM employee
WHERE RuleUID = (SELECT CONCAT(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(RuleUID,1,CHARINDEX('_',RuleUID)-1) AS INT)), '_rule') 
                 FROM employee)
```

If you don't want to use subqueries, you could use a `CTE` with either `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT firstname, lastname, RuleUID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(RuleUID,1,CHARINDEX('_',RuleUID)-1) AS INT) DESC) AS rn
FROM employee)
SELECT firstname, lastname, RuleUID
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

or `RANK()`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT firstname, lastname, RuleUID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(RuleUID,1,CHARINDEX('_',RuleUID)-1) AS INT) DESC) AS rn
FROM employee)
SELECT firstname, lastname, RuleUID
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Finally, you could use a simple `TOP` query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 firstname
    , lastname
    , RuleUID
FROM employee
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(RuleUID,1,CHARINDEX('_',RuleUID)-1) AS INT) DESC
```

In all cases the output (for my demo) is the same:

```
firstname   lastname    RuleUID
someone     else        120_rule
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=e2ad69ef7d02940f57282bc69f13404e)

Comment: Hi Nick, I need something more simpler like choosing the RuleUID which evaluates to that MAX criteria then and there itself, without diving into sub queries. This is due to performance reasons.

Comment: @cmn1 because you need the firstname and lastname associated with the `MAX` value, you either need to use subqueries, or you could use a CTE. See my edit for a couple of examples of that.

Comment: @cmn1 Added one more alternative for you using `TOP`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select firstname, 
    lastname, 
    replace(ltrim(replace(MAX(RIGHT('0000000000' + RuleUID, 10)), '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
        as MaxRule
    from employee
    group by firstname, lastname
```

Comment: This is selecting MaxRule, I need to select RuleUid that evaluates to that MAX criteria

Comment: @cmn1 The change will leave the rule that is the max. Something like 122_rule.

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered low quality. Could you add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `order by`  and get the `top 1` in descending order.

**sql server**

```
select firstname
    , lastname
    , RuleUID
from employee
order by substring(RuleUID,1,charindex('_',RuleUID)-1) desc
```

**mysql**

```
select top 1 firstname
    , lastname
    , RuleUID
from employee
order by substring(RuleUID,1,charindex('_',RuleUID)-1) desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are going to need to pull the number out of the RuleUID a lot. So make a function you can reuse:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getRuleNo(@ruleUID varchar(50))  
RETURNS int   
AS   
BEGIN  

  RETURN CAST(SUBSTRING(@ruleUID, 1, CHARINDEX('_',@ruleUID) - 1) AS INT)

END;
GO
```

Then use that function for this problem and others:

```
select firstname, 
lastname, 
CAST(MAX(dbo.getRuleNo(RuleUID)) AS VARCHAR) + '_rule' as MaxRule
from employee
group by firstname, lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we sort by LEN(RuleUID) DESC. Then by RuleUID DESC. The first one is your max. Now you don't need the GROUP BY.

```
    ;WITH cte AS
    (
       SELECT LastName, FirstName, RuleUID,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LastName, FirstName 
             ORDER BY LEN(RuleUID) DESC, RuleUID DESC) AS rn
       FROM Employees
    )


    SELECT *
    FROM cte
    WHERE rn = 1
    ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
```

This should give 1 row for each name along with their max RuleUID.